# error while loading shared libraries: libboost_mpi.so.1.65.1 : no such file or directory - even though the file is there

Tags: ubuntu, boost, mpi

libboost_mpi.so.1.65.1 is located under /home/batuhan/usr/lib as you can see [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo3Yr.png)

But even though I give library path I cannot run my program, see [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7uuw.png)

How can I overcome this, I spent hours trying to get around this error but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please edit your question and copy/paste the message, there is no point fir having a screenshot here.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** put your library path into the environment too:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/batuhan/usr/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

I am assuming a shared home directory across your compute nodes here, i.e. the library file is available on the computers where your MPI processes execute.

**More detail:** You can also pass it via `mpirun` using the `-env` option. The exact name of the option might differ depending on your MPI implementation (try `man mpirun`).

```
-env <name> <value>
```

If you wanted to hard-code the library path into your executable during compilation you could use the `-rpath` option of the linker, which you can pass through in your compiler call by:

```
mpic++ -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/batuhan/usr/lib <etc..>
```

You can check the resolution of dynamic libraries using

```
ldd <executable>
```

Hope that helps.